# Populating MongoDB with sample documents including current datetime

Tags: mongodb, mongoimport

I'm trying to populate my **MongoDB** with sample data to run a performance test. My documents are meant to have a `datetime` field named `last_update` which I believe is self describing.

In order to have conclusive results I need a lot of documents (starting from 1M going to 1G). That's why I decided to use a tool like `mongoimport` to populate my collection.

Here's a line from my `json` file that I'm feeding to `mongoimport`:

```
{ "counter" : 0, "last_update" : new Date() }
```

I'm expecting each document to have the current `datetime` as it is saved into collection. But `mongoimport` exits with an error:

```
exception:BSON representation of supplied JSON is too large: code FailedToParse: FailedToParse: Expecting '}' or ',': offset:42
```

It seems `mongoimport` has a problem with `new Date()` statement. So my question is how can I add bulk number of documents into a collection with a field set to current time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"The mongoimport tool provides a route to import content from a JSON, CSV, or TSV export created by mongoexport, or potentially, another third-party export tool." Hence i think u cannot use `new Date();` in the json file. Try to insert data by using a javascript file.

```
db.collection.insert({ "counter" : 0, "last_update" : new Date() });
```

then use command `127.0.0.1/db new.js` 
Otherwise u should give the datestring in the json to insert docs using mongoimport

Comment: Thanks, I've got your point but you may want to clarify your answer as it's a little hard to get.